# JavaScript: Smooth Scroll Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, Smooth scroll is not working. I believe that there is something in my HTML causing the problem. Click on ***Food delivery*** or anything in that list to test it, in the code. I appreciate any extra eyes on this :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  /* For the sticky navigation */
  $('.js--section-features').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == "down") {
      $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  }, {
    offset: '60px;'
  });


  /* Scroll on buttons*/
  $('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.js--section-plans').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('.js--scroll-to-start').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.js--section-features').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });


  /* Navigation scroll*/
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });


  /* Animations on scroll */
  $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });

  $('.js--wp-2').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });

  $('.js--wp-3').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-3').addClass('animated fadeIn');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });

  $('.js--wp-4').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-4').addClass('animated pulse');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });


  /* Map */
  var map = new GMaps({
    div: '.map',
    lat: 38.7436266,
    lng: -9.07,
    zoom: 12
  });

  map.addMarker({
    lat: 38.7436266,
    lng: -9.1602037,
    title: 'Lima',
    infoWindow: {
      content: '<p>Our Lisbon Headquarters</p>'
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Healthy foods is the #1 meal prep company in 2017!">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/v/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/v/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/v/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/r/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/r/queries.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/img/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/img/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <!-- Favicons -->

  <!-- Goolge Analytics -->
  <!-- Goolge Analytics -->

  <title>Healthy Foods</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Omni Food Logo" class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Omni Food Logo" class="logo-black">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="#features">Food delivery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#works">How it works</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#cities">Our cities</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#plans">Sign up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Conact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Goodbye junk food.<br>Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
      <a class="btn btn-full js--scroll-to-plans" href="#plans">I'm hungry</a>
      <a class="btn btn-ghost js--scroll-to-start" href="#features">Show me more</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Food Fast Section Title -->
  <section class="js--section-features" id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <center>
        <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food.</h2>
      </center>
      <p class="long-copy">
        Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
    </div>
    <!-- Get Food Fast Section Content -->
    <br>
    <div class="row js--wp-1">
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-calendar icon-big"></i>
        <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
        <p class="section-content">Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-clock icon-big"></i>
        <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
        <p class="section-content">You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-ios-nutrition icon-big"></i>
        <h3>100% organic</h3>
        <p class="section-content">All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-android-cart icon-big"></i>
        <h3>Order anything</h3>
        <p class="section-content">We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Get Food Fast Section Content -->
  <!-- Favorite Meals Section -->
  <section class="section-meals">
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <ul class="meals-showcase clearfix">
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Simple italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <ul class="meals-showcase clearfix">
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="Paleo beef steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="Healthy baguette with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="Burger with cheddar and bacon">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="Granola with cherries and strawberries">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <!-- Favorite Meals Section End -->
  <!-- How it works Section -->
  <section class="section-steps" id="works">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>How it works - Simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-1-of-2 steps-box">
        <img src="img/app-iPhone.png" alt="Omifood app on iPhone" class="app-screen js--wp-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-2 steps-box">
        <div class="work-step">
          <div>1</div>
          <p>Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign up today.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="work-step">
          <div>2</div>
          <p>Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or you can even call us!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="work-step">
          <div>3</div>
          <p>Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next time!</p>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="btn-app">
          <img src="img/download-app-android.png" alt="Play Store Button">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-app">
          <img src="img/download-app-android.png" alt="Play Store Button">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- How it works Section End -->
    <section class="section-cities js--wp-3" id="cities">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>We're currently in these cities</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- Lisbon -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/lisbon-3.jpg" alt="Lisbon">
          <h3>Lisbon</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            1600+ happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            60+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_lx</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- San Francisco -->
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Francisco">
          <h3>San Francisco</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            +3700 happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            160+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_sf</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Berlin -->
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/berlin.jpg" alt="Berlin">
          <h3>Berlin</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            +2300 happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            110+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_berlin</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- London -->
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/london.jpg" alt="London">
          <h3>Berlin</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            +1200 happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            50+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_london</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Cities Section End -->
    <!-- Testimonials Section Start -->
    <section class="section-testimonials">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
            <cite><img src="img/customer-1.jpg" alt="Customer 1">Alberto Duncan</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            Inexpensive, healthy and great-tasting meals, delivered right to my home. We have lots of food delivery here in Lisbon, but no one comes even close to Omifood. Me and my family are so in love!
            <cite><img src="img/customer-2.jpg" alt="Customer 2">Joana Silva</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            I was looking for a quick and easy food delivery service in San Franciso. I tried a lot of them and ended up with Omnifood. Best food delivery service in the Bay Area. Keep up the great work!
            <cite><img src="img/customer-3.jpg" alt="Customer 3">Milton Chapman</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Testimonials Section End -->
    <!-- Signup Section Start -->

    <section class="section-plans js--section-plans" id="plans">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Start eating healthy today</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <div class="plan-box js--wp-4">
            <div>
              <h3>Premium</h3>
              <p class="plan-price">$399 <span>/ month</span>
              </p>
              <p class="plan-price-meal">That's only 13.30$ per meal</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>1 meal every day</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Order 24/7</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Access to newest creations</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Free delivery</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-full">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <div class="plan-box js--wp-4">
            <div>
              <h3>Pro</h3>
              <p class="plan-price">$149 <span>/ month</span>
              </p>
              <p class="plan-price-meal">That's only 14.90$ per meal</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>1 meal 10 days/month</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Order 24/7</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Access to newest creations</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Free delivery</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <div class="plan-box js--wp-4">
            <div>
              <h3>Starter</h3>
              <p class="plan-price">19$ <span>/ meal</span>
              </p>
              <p class="plan-price-meal">&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>1 meal</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Order from 8 am to 12 pm</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-close-empty icon-small"></i>
                </li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Free delivery</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Signup Section End -->
    <!-- Form Section Section -->

    <div class="map-box">
      <div class="map"></div>
      <div class="form-box" id="contact">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>We're happy to hear from you</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label for="find-us">How did you find us?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <select name="find-us" id="find-us">
                  <option value="friends" selected>Friends</option>
                  <option value="search">Search engine</option>
                  <option value="ad">Advertisement</option>
                  <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>Newsletter?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="news" id="news" checked>Yes, please
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>Drop us a line</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Form Section End -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <footer>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
          <ul class="footer-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">iOS App</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Android App</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
          <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p>
          Healthy Foods © 2016-2017
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Footer End -->

    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to run your own snippet? - you commented out the place where it loads jquery ... but you use jquery ... wonder what the problem is

Comment: Why you commented this min js **https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js** uncomment this min js it'll work for your reference please find this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eb786urv/2/)

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out. I think I had the wrong jquery source file on my computer. Re-downloaded the correct version and fixed the problem.

Comment: If your problem has been fixed, please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so it can be mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below snippet just uncomment
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
 this min js it'll required to other js work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
debugger;
  $('.js--section-features').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction == "down") {
      $('nav').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  }, {
    offset: '60px;'
  });


  /* Scroll on buttons*/
  $('.js--scroll-to-plans').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.js--section-plans').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });

  $('.js--scroll-to-start').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.js--section-features').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });


  /* Navigation scroll*/
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });


  /* Animations on scroll */
  $('.js--wp-1').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-1').addClass('animated fadeIn');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });

  $('.js--wp-2').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });

  $('.js--wp-3').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-3').addClass('animated fadeIn');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });

  $('.js--wp-4').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.js--wp-4').addClass('animated pulse');
  }, {
    offset: '50%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

      <div class="row">
        <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Omni Food Logo" class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Omni Food Logo" class="logo-black">
        <ul class="main-nav">
          <li><a href="#features">Food delivery</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#works">How it works</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#cities">Our cities</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#plans">Sign up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Conact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Goodbye junk food.<br>Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
      <a class="btn btn-full js--scroll-to-plans" href="#plans">I'm hungry</a>
      <a class="btn btn-ghost js--scroll-to-start" href="#features">Show me more</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Food Fast Section Title -->
  <section class="js--section-features" id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <center>
        <h2>Get food fast &mdash; not fast food.</h2>
      </center>
      <p class="long-copy">
        Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
    </div>
    <!-- Get Food Fast Section Content -->
    <br>
    <div class="row js--wp-1">
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-calendar icon-big"></i>
        <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
        <p class="section-content">Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-clock icon-big"></i>
        <h3>Ready in 20 minutes</h3>
        <p class="section-content">You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-ios-nutrition icon-big"></i>
        <h3>100% organic</h3>
        <p class="section-content">All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
        <i class="ion-android-cart icon-big"></i>
        <h3>Order anything</h3>
        <p class="section-content">We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Get Food Fast Section Content -->
  <!-- Favorite Meals Section -->
  <section class="section-meals">
    <!-- Row 1 -->
    <ul class="meals-showcase clearfix">
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Simple italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Row 2 -->
    <ul class="meals-showcase clearfix">
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/5.jpg" alt="Paleo beef steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/6.jpg" alt="Healthy baguette with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="Burger with cheddar and bacon">
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="meal-photo">
          <img src="img/8.jpg" alt="Granola with cherries and strawberries">
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <!-- Favorite Meals Section End -->
  <!-- How it works Section -->
  <section class="section-steps" id="works">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>How it works - Simple as 1, 2, 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col span-1-of-2 steps-box">
        <img src="img/app-iPhone.png" alt="Omifood app on iPhone" class="app-screen js--wp-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col span-1-of-2 steps-box">
        <div class="work-step">
          <div>1</div>
          <p>Choose the subscription plan that best fits your needs and sign up today.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="work-step">
          <div>2</div>
          <p>Order your delicious meal using our mobile app or website. Or you can even call us!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="work-step">
          <div>3</div>
          <p>Enjoy your meal after less than 20 minutes. See you the next time!</p>
        </div>

        <a href="#" class="btn-app">
          <img src="img/download-app-android.png" alt="Play Store Button">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn-app">
          <img src="img/download-app-android.png" alt="Play Store Button">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- How it works Section End -->
    <section class="section-cities js--wp-3" id="cities">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>We're currently in these cities</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- Lisbon -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/lisbon-3.jpg" alt="Lisbon">
          <h3>Lisbon</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            1600+ happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            60+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_lx</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- San Francisco -->
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/san-francisco.jpg" alt="San Francisco">
          <h3>San Francisco</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            +3700 happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            160+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_sf</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Berlin -->
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/berlin.jpg" alt="Berlin">
          <h3>Berlin</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            +2300 happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            110+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_berlin</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- London -->
        <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
          <img src="img/london.jpg" alt="London">
          <h3>Berlin</h3>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-person icon-small"></i>
            +1200 happy eaters
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-ios-star icon-small"></i>
            50+ top chefs
          </div>
          <div class="city-feature">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter icon-small"></i>
            <a href="#">@omnifood_london</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Cities Section End -->
    <!-- Testimonials Section Start -->
    <section class="section-testimonials">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Our customers can't live without us</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            Omnifood is just awesome! I just launched a startup which leaves me with no time for cooking, so Omnifood is a life-saver. Now that I got used to it, I couldn't live without my daily meals!
            <cite><img src="img/customer-1.jpg" alt="Customer 1">Alberto Duncan</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            Inexpensive, healthy and great-tasting meals, delivered right to my home. We have lots of food delivery here in Lisbon, but no one comes even close to Omifood. Me and my family are so in love!
            <cite><img src="img/customer-2.jpg" alt="Customer 2">Joana Silva</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <blockquote>
            I was looking for a quick and easy food delivery service in San Franciso. I tried a lot of them and ended up with Omnifood. Best food delivery service in the Bay Area. Keep up the great work!
            <cite><img src="img/customer-3.jpg" alt="Customer 3">Milton Chapman</cite>
          </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Testimonials Section End -->
    <!-- Signup Section Start -->

    <section class="section-plans js--section-plans" id="plans">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Start eating healthy today</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <div class="plan-box js--wp-4">
            <div>
              <h3>Premium</h3>
              <p class="plan-price">$399 <span>/ month</span>
              </p>
              <p class="plan-price-meal">That's only 13.30$ per meal</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>1 meal every day</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Order 24/7</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Access to newest creations</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Free delivery</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-full">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <div class="plan-box js--wp-4">
            <div>
              <h3>Pro</h3>
              <p class="plan-price">$149 <span>/ month</span>
              </p>
              <p class="plan-price-meal">That's only 14.90$ per meal</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>1 meal 10 days/month</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Order 24/7</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Access to newest creations</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Free delivery</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
          <div class="plan-box js--wp-4">
            <div>
              <h3>Starter</h3>
              <p class="plan-price">19$ <span>/ meal</span>
              </p>
              <p class="plan-price-meal">&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>1 meal</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Order from 8 am to 12 pm</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-close-empty icon-small"></i>
                </li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark-empty icon-small"></i>Free delivery</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost">Sign up now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Signup Section End -->
    <!-- Form Section Section -->

    <div class="map-box">
      <div class="map"></div>
      <div class="form-box" id="contact">
        <div class="row">
          <h2>We're happy to hear from you</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <form method="post" action="#" class="contact-form">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label for="find-us">How did you find us?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <select name="find-us" id="find-us">
                  <option value="friends" selected>Friends</option>
                  <option value="search">Search engine</option>
                  <option value="ad">Advertisement</option>
                  <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>Newsletter?</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="news" id="news" checked>Yes, please
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>Drop us a line</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col span-1-of-3">
                <label>&nbsp;</label>
              </div>
              <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Form Section End -->

    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <footer>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
          <ul class="footer-nav">
            <li><a href="#">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">iOS App</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Android App</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-2">
          <ul class="social-icons">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-facebook"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-twitter"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="ion-social-instagram"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p>
          Healthy Foods © 2016-2017
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thank you, problem has been fixed!

Comment: @Isaiah Ohh glad it help feel free to mark as accepted answer as well for future references